# need help matching wires

Tags: electrical, lighting

[image]

So we used to have this ugly rusted chandelier in our dining room, but recently we decided to take it off. When removed we saw the above scene. I am now confused about which of the 2 wires/bundles with black I should connect to the black wire on the new light fixture we want to install, and which wire/bundle with white should connect to the same on the fixture. Also, the switch attached to this fixture was a dimmer switch, which we also replaced. I did try and use a circuit tester quote "for auto systems" and couldn't get it to light up in with any combination I tried.  I would so appreciate any help. I would like to be able to use the dining room again some day.

Comment: If "for auto systems" means "for cars" then it is likely DC not AC and won't light up. Can you post a picture of the switch box showing the switch and all wires in the box?

Comment: Use a mains rated tester or multimeter and find the one that goes live with switch operation - or possibly the switch connects the bulb to neutral but that is not usually taken as best practice.

Comment: If you're going to be removing a lot of ugly fixtures and switches, take pictures before you unhook any wire..... you'll thank me later...  and we'll thank you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a switch loop, notice the white with the group of blacks, that white goes down to the switch and the switched power is on the single black wire (if you look close that white with the black will be in the same cable as the single black)  so your black on the light goes to the single black. The white on the light to the group of whites and grounds together if the lamp has one. (Plastic lamps may not have a ground, the white with the black wires should be marked usually black or with black tape but any color besides white, gray or green would meet code.) the marking of a switch loop is often overlooked/ not done.

Comment: The white wire in the group of black wires should be marked, usually with black tape, to show it's an always hot. I'd hate to have the OP mess with it to tape it so maybe mark it with a magic marker.+

Comment: Okay, so I connected the wires as you described and, like magic, it worked. Thank you for the quick and helpful answer, I wasn't sure how long it would take to get a response honestly.

Comment: If the question has the info we need and especially a photo like you provided there are a few of us that check the site several times a day and can answer. Good questions should get up votes the same as helpful answers and comment , we hope to see you back.